# Stream.Read doesn't return anything if nothing has been sent

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, stream

I'm trying to receive data via bluetooth in Xamarin.Android. If I have data to receive, my method work fine. But if nothing has been sent, nothing is returned from Stream.Read method (`_inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
private Stream _inputStream;

public string ReceiveData()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[30];

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int read = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (read <= 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            char[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer);

            if (!result[0].Equals("\0"))
            {
                return result[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Não implementado
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is in the line `_inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`. If nothing has been sent via bluetooth, I get stuck in it. Nothing is returned, no exception is raised.

**EDIT 1**

As @rene suggested, I tried with Task/Async with a CancellationToken with 1500 ms. I get the same behavior.

```
public async Task<string> ReceiveData()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[30];
    CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    token.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int read = await _inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token.Token);

            if (read <= 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            char[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer);

            if (!result[0].Equals("\0"))
            {
                return result[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Não implementado
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should execute it async  (Task/Thread) with a cancel option

Comment: @rene I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: @rene Stil the same behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273752/how-to-cancel-networkstream-readasync-without-closing-stream

Comment: How about set a [ReadTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) to your input stream.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told by James Harmon in [Cancel ReadAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273752/how-to-cancel-networkstream-readasync-without-closing-stream), it is not possible to cancel an Stream.ReadAsync since the internal call is unmanaged and uses IOCompletion ports.

He suggest three options to get around this:

1. Use Socket.Shutdown(). This will return ReadAsync with a socket error of OperationAborted.
2. Wait for the read to timeout.
3. Check if data is available before reading from the socket.

I opted for the third option by checking if data is available before reading the socket.

My final code:

```
public async Task<string> ReceiveData()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[30];

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(_inputStream.IsDataAvailable())
            {
                int read = await _inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (read <= 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                char[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer);

                if (!result[0].Equals("\0"))
                {
                    return result[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Não implementado
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thank you very much H.G. Sandhagen.