# Stream CopyToAsync - Detect client disconnection and set a timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing a `ConnectionHandler` as a part of Kestrel. The idea is that when a client connects, the `ConnectionHandler` opens a socket with another server in the network, gets a continuous stream of data and forwards them back to the client. In the meantime, the client can also send data to the `ConnectionHandler` that the latter is constantly forwarding to the other server in the network (opened socket).

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext connection)
{
  TcpClient serverSocket = TcpClient(address, port);
  serverSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
  serverSocket.SendTimeout = 10000;

  NetworkStream dataStream = serverSocket.GetStream();
  dataStream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
  dataStream.WriteTimeout = 10000;

  Stream clientStreamOut = connection.Transport.Output.AsStream();
  Stream clientStreamIn = connection.Transport.Input.AsStream();

  Task dataTask = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
      try
      {
          await dataStream.CopyToAsync(clientStreamOut);
      }
      catch
      {
          await LogsHelper.Log(logStream, LogsHelper.BROKEN_CLIENT_STREAM);
          return;
      }
  }, connection.ConnectionClosed);

  Task clientTask = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
      try
      {
          await clientStreamIn.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
      }
      catch
      {
          await LogsHelper.Log(logStream, LogsHelper.BROKEN_DATA_STREAM);
          return;
      }
  }, connection.ConnectionClosed);
  await Task.WhenAny(dataTask, clientTask);
}
```

I am encountering 3 issues:

1. For the socket with the other server, I am using a `TcpClient` and I use a `NetworkStream`. Even though I am setting both `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` to 10 seconds, for both `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream`, the opened socket is waiting forever, even if the other server in the network does not send any data for 5 minutes.
2. Setting timeout for `clientStreamOut` and `clientStreamIn (e.g: clientStreamIn.ReadTimeout = 10000;)` is also failing with an exception that it's not supported for that particular stream. I was wondering, is it possible somehow to provide a timeout?
3. When a client connects to the `ConnectionHandler`, `OnConnectedAsync` is triggered. The issue with the code comes when a client disconnects (either due to network drop or for whatever reason). Sometimes disconnection of the client is being detected and the session terminates, while other times it hangs forever, even if the client has actually been disconnected. I was expecting that `CopyToAsync` will throw an exception in case of a disconnection since I assume that `CopyToAsync` is trying to write, but that's **not always** the case.

`connection.ConnectionClosed` is a `CancellationToken` that comes from `OnConnectedAsync`, I read here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23207 that it can be used in `CopyToAsync`. However, I am not sure how I can use it. Also, it is worth to mention that I have zero control over the client code.

I am running the app using Docker

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12421989/25182 has answers for `ReadAsync` timeouts, but they could be adapted to a `CopyToAsync` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` properties only apply to synchronous reads/writes, not asynchronous ones.

For asynchronous code, you'll need to implement your own read timeouts (write timeouts are generally unnecessary). E.g., use `Task.Delay` and kill the connection if data isn't received in that time.